# Large MS SQL Server table very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

I do have quite a general question, however, I have searched for the answer a lot and nothing has helped so far.

I have a database with only one table, but a large one - 182 million rows, about 30 columns. The design should be optimized enough, as I used the design of the original database (where the data were exported from at the client).

The database sits on the external drive with USB 3.0.A simple SELECT COUNT(*) to count the rows took hour and a half. Fields are mostly "real" and nvarchar(2-10)

I would be grateful if you could point me in some direction - maybe I completely miss an important point?

Comment: `The database sits on the external drive` *that's* what's slow. In any case, you haven't posted any query that you want to accelerate. The simple `SELECT COUNT(*)` has to scan the entire table to find matching rows before it can count them. That performance is the worst you can expect and won't benefit from any indexing. The field types don't matter

Comment: What is the question

Comment: And what does the `explain plan` say?

Comment: Storing databases on an external device is rarely a good idea I'm afraid. There's are so many problems that can occur; and performance is just one of them. Ease of corruption is a biggy (for example, someone "accidentally" removes the device from the USB port).

Comment: Looks like you extracted a star schema to a database but placed it on extremely slow IO storage. This will *always* be slow, even with indexing. You can reduce the IO cost by using compression, although compressing so much data over such a slow connection will take a *lot* of time.

Comment: "The design should be optimized"  How so?  Do you have indexes?  Have your run statistics on them on the new drive?

Comment: https://sqlbak.com/blog/update-statistics-sql-server/

Comment: "The database sits on the external drive with USB 3.0."  You've got to be kidding me.

Comment: Should move the database to local SSD. data is huge SSD will be in this case.

Comment: Show us the query(ies)!

Comment: external hard drive very slow ..

Comment: For a simple count, follow the advise on [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/07/15/sql-server-how-to-quickly-retrieve-accurate-row-count-for-table.aspx). The physical location of the database is also a problem. As mentioned, you should show actual queries and DDL for the table and indexes.